# Get RGB pixel value on mouse click event on ImageView

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, imageview, pixel

I am displaying the image in ImageView by preserving aspect ratio of image.
I want to pick the color of pixel whenever user clicks on one.

Here is what I am doing right now:

```
@FXML private ImageView chosenImage;
Color color = chosenImage.getImage().getPixelReader().getColor((int) mouseEvent.getX(), (int) mouseEvent.getY());
```

Here is the FXML code for ImageView:

```
<ImageView fx:id="chosenImage" fitHeight="380.0" fitWidth="252.0" onMouseClicked="#onImageClicked" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" smooth="false" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="8.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="8.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="294.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="8.0" />
```

This does get some value but it's not accurate. The X and Y value from mouse event is with respect to ImageView and not the image it self.
I want to get pixel value of the clicked region somehow.

If anyone knows a solution, please help. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to get the color of one pixel in the `ImageView`?

Comment: @LAD right. When a user clicks on it with cursor.

Comment: When I test this the result is pretty accurate. There are a multiple properties influence how the image coordinates are calculated from the `ImageView` coordinates: `viewport`, `preserveAspectRatio`, `fitHeight` and `fitWidth`. If the latter 2 are set this can lead to problems since probably smoothing is involved.

Comment: @fabian I have added fxml code of this imageview question. Can you please have a look and let me know where I am wrong?

Comment: @fabian Thanks for pointing out about fitHeight and fitWidth, I just removed these two properties from my fxml and the code is now working pretty accurately. 
You can post your answer and I'll then mark it as correct one :) Thanks a lot once again.